# If you Broke Mars' Perclorates and Benzenes How Much of an Atmosphere Would this Create?

Tags: hard-science, climate, terraforming

Much of Mars is inimical to human life.  While there are many problems I would like to focus on three:

1. The low density atmosphere does not provide the pressure needed to
   sustain humans outside of a pressured device -- suit, living
   structure, ... etc.
2. The presence of perclorates in the martian soil are toxic to humans
   and perhaps other forms of life.

   Martian soil is estimated to have 0.5 grams per liter of perclorate
   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_soil, 2023-11-23).
   Perclorates are notorious for causing severe thyroid problems
   (https://www.fda.gov/food/environmental-contaminants-food/perchlorate-questions-and-answers, 2023-11-23)
3. Some evidence (cited below) suggests that at least some of the
   water on Mars contains benzenes, which are carcinogenic and in
   addition toxic too humans and other forms of life.

   Some samples of martian water have evidence of benzenes
   (https://arstechnica.com/science/2023/07/organic-chemicals-on-mars-are-associated-with-water-shaped-deposits/, 2023-11-23).  Benzenes have have been determined to cause cancer
   amongst possible other health issues (https://emergency.cdc.gov/agent/benzene/basics/facts.asp, 2023-11-23).

If all of the perclorate and benzene on Mars were broken down gases atmospheric at higher atmospheric pressure (such as O2, methane, carbon dioxide, ...), how much atmosphere would this potentially produce?

Comment: Broken down into what? Carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, calcium, and chlorine? Carbon, methane, hydrochloric acid, calcium oxide? Etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how answerable this is. given that it requires some very broad and sweeping generalisations about the composition and volume of regolith on mars, especially given your "hard science" requirement. You might possibly get better answers on a more science-focused stack, maybe.

Comment: And more critically, how long would it last given that Mars does not have the magnetic field needed to protect against the solar particles which would strip away the atmosphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_of_Mars

Comment: @StarfishPrime Fair.

Comment: @AlexP A fair criticism.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Do you think the question could be fixed by changing it to Science Based?

Comment: @DavidR: It will last for millions of years. Certainly it will last for long enough to be of no concern on human life or human history timescales.

Comment: @AlexP I've made a modification to address your criticism.  Let me know if this is sufficient. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Maybe. I would say that what would really be helpful is have the question focus on a specific process, that is, for example, I want to have lots of furnaces which will roast calcium perchlorate $\ce{Ca(ClO4)2}$ and break it down into calcium oxide $\ce{CaO}$, chlorine and oxygen. Or maybe take both calcium perchlorate and benzene, and make limestone = calcium carbonate $\ce{CaCO3}$, methane, and chlorine. (The big issue is what you do with the chlorine. An atmosphere of chlorine is not helpful, like, at all.)

Comment: @AlexP  The issue is that I would like to use bioengineered micro-organisms perform this transformation.  Unfortunately this leads to the universal sci-fi problem solver: Nanites.  Anything can be solved with nanite... ....I may vomit from using the trope.

Comment: That's mechanics. *How* you do the chemical transformation has no impact on *what* you want to get or on *how much* of it you get. You can convert sugar into ethyl alcohol using yeast in a vat or using industrial chemistry, but in the end you get the same ethyl alcohol.

Comment: The challenge is to make the new atmosphere fast enough to compensate for the current solar wind which is stripping gas away at the rate of 100g/sec on the low end (higher during solar storms). https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/nasa-mission-reveals-speed-of-solar-wind-stripping-martian-atmosphere/ As you build up the atmosphere, more will be lost to solar wind.

Comment: @DavidR This is awesome!

Comment: While it may be possible to estimate the amount of benzene to convert (maybe), how much of the crust are we to process? You need up to 18 inches to grow food and 3 feet to grow trees as a minimum. You're going to want to process deeper than that to have a hope of toxins not seeping up to poison the plants. Maybe a half kilometer? If we ignore asking how to get the converted perclorates out of soil that deep, this is really just a math problem, isn't it? My high school chem class was a long time ago, but once you have a formula, it's just mass in gives you mass out.

Comment: @JBH oddly enough some of these comments sound like posts.

Comment: @JBH I might be able to modify my question based on this.  Unfortunetaly, I need a substitute for N2, which would be virtually impossible to find.

Answer (score 0):

Given the density differences, it would make more than Earth's atmospheric pressure and more, easily. The problem is, there is no way that I can think of to break down these perclorates and benzenes fast/industrially and not demolish/cook the whole surface with them.

A dubious, and extremely slow solution would be to engineer microbes that can eat these chemicals and convert them to greenhouse gasses, but I'm not sure how would you kick-start the process on the frigid, arid and vacuum adjacent surface of Mars.